# Code works in jsFiddle but not in my brower

Tags: javascript

My javascript code works in jsfiddle but it doesn't work on my browser.
Can anyone help me please. thanks in advance.
Here is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
<title> BMI Calculator </title>
<meta charset= "UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylev1.cs">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jsv1.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
Height (cm):
<input type="range" id="height" onchange="this.setAttribute('value',this.value);" min="100" max="250" step="0.1" value="0" />

<br>
Weight (kg):
<input type="range" id="weight" onchange="this.setAttribute('value',this.value);" min="0" max="200" step="0.1" value="0" />

<br>
Your BMI : 
<div id="displaybmi" value="" >   </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Javascript file:

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function( ($("#height")||("#weight")).change(function(e) {    
                    var height, weight;
                    height = parseFloat($('#height').val());
                    height = height/100;
                    weight = parseFloat($('#weight').val()); 

                    $('#displaybmi').html(calbmi(weight,height)); 

                  function calbmi(){

                    var bmi = weight/(height*height);
                    return bmi;

                }   


        })));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wm81/935fnmyx/9/

Comment: ``onchange="this.setAttribute('value',this.value);"``, why, just why?

Comment: `($("#height")||("#weight")).change` isn't correct. It's equivalent to `($("#height")).change`, since `||` returns the first truthy argument. If you want to bind to multiple selectors, use `$("#height, #weight").change`.

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't work". What is it supposed to do, and how does it fail? Do you see any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: In your fiddle, you call `calculatebmi` with 2 arguments, but it doesn't have any parameter variables, and it doesn't have a `return` statement.

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow, when asking a question please describe the desired behavior, also specifically what the problem is, within the question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: In `updatestatus()`, you do `$("#comment").value = "Underweight";` You're mixing up DOM properties and jQuery functions there. Honestly, there's so many things wrong with your code, I don't kow where to start.

Comment: Your question says it works in the fiddle, but that's just not true. Maybe you linked to the wrong fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript / jQuery has quite a lot of errors.

You need to read about:

- Callbacks - you have passed some sort or argument to jQuery's [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) callback.
- jQuery [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) - you haven't used an actual jQuery selector for `#weight`; it is missing the dollar sign, and you can pick either of them in one selector - much like CSS.
- Variable [scope](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) and function parameters - you have passed parameters to the calbmi function but have not actual parameters in the signature.  It was just using the variables of the same name from the local scope.

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cch9dce3/2/) and compare the differences.

**JS**

```
$("#height, #weight").on( 'change', function () {

    var height, weight;
    height = parseFloat($('#height').val());
    height = height / 100;
    weight = parseFloat($('#weight').val());
    var bmi = calbmi(weight, height);

    $('#displaybmi').html(bmi);

});


function calbmi(weight, height) {

    var bmi = weight / (height * height);
    return bmi;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    Height (cm):
    <input type="range" id="height" min="100" max="250" step="0.1" value="0" />
    <br>Weight (kg):
    <input type="range" id="weight" min="0" max="200" step="0.1" value="0" />
    <br>Your BMI :
    <div id="displaybmi"></div>
</div>
```